# How to loop over an entire method until you achieve what you want ? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, loops

I'm learning ruby and practicing with codewars, and I've come to a challenge that I feel I mainly understand (rudimentarily) but I'm unable to figure out how to continue looping over the method until I reach the result I'm looking for.

The challenge is asking to reduce a number, by multiplying its digits, until the multiplication results in a single digit. In the end it wants you to return the number of times you had to multiply the number until you arrived at a single digit. Example -> given -> 39;  3 * 9 = 27, 2 * 7 = 14, 1 * 4 = 4;  answer -> 3

Here's my code :

```
def persistence(n)

  if n < 10
    return 0
  end

  arr = n.to_s.split("") 
  sum = 1 
  count = 0 
  arr.each do |num| 
    sum *= num.to_i 
    if num == arr[-1]
      count += 1
    end
  end

  if sum < 10
    return count 
  else
    persistence(sum)  
  end
    
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is looking great with recursion but you are reseting the  count variable to 0 each time the loop runs, I think if you use an auxiliar method it should run ok:

*this is in base of your code with minor improvements*:

```rb
def persistence(n)
  return 0 if n < 10
  count = 0

  multiply_values(n, count)
end

def multiply_values(n, count)
  arr = n.to_s.chars
  sum = 1
  arr.each do |num| 
    sum *= num.to_i 
    if num == arr[-1]
      count += 1
    end
  end

  if sum < 10
    return count 
  else
    multiply_values(sum, count)  
  end
end
```

a shorter solution could be to do:

```rb
def persistence(n)
  return 0 if n < 10
  multiply_values(n, 1)
end

def multiply_values(n, count)
  sum = n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:*)
  return count if sum < 10
    
  multiply_values(sum, count + 1)  
end
```

and without recursion:

```rb
def persistence(n)
  return 0 if n < 10

  count = 0
  while n > 10
    n = n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:*)
    count += 1
  end
  count
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a nicer way to do this once:

```
num = 1234
product = num.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).reduce(&:*)
```

Breaking it down:

```
num.to_s.split("")
```

As you know, this gets us `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`. We can easily get back to `[1, 2, 3, 4]` by mapping the `#to_i` method to each string in that array.

```
num.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i)
```

We then need to multiply them together. `#reduce` is a handy method. We can pass it a block:

```
num.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).reduce { |a, b| a * b }
```

Or take a shortcut:

```
num.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).reduce(&:*)
```

As for looping, you could employ recursion, and create `product_of_digits` as a new method for `Integer`.

```
class Integer
   def product_of_digits
      if self < 10
         self
      else
         self.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i).reduce(&:*).product_of_digits
      end
   end
end
```

We can now simply call this method on any integer.

```
1344.product_of_digits # => 6
```

Comment: Any questions about any of it, feel free to ask. :)